# My ps Plus Account ended. when I renew, will I get back the items I got using Ps Plus?

Tags: playstation-plus

I forgot to renew my ps plus account and it ended. When I will renew but I was wondering. Will I get my games back when I renew my account or am I doomed?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Once you've 'purchased' an Instant Game Collection game with PSPlus, you can access it as long as you're subscribed. Subscribe again, and you can access it again (or download it again, if you need to).

From the [PlayStation Plus FAQ](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/Forum-Frequently-Asked-Questions/PlayStation-Plus-FAQ/td-p/37512373):

> Q: What happens to the games and Add-Ons I downloaded free through a PS Plus membership, and I decide to not renew my membership?
>
> A: If you do not renew your PS Plus membership, you will not be able to access previous free games downloaded with Plus. If you have purchased Add-Ons for a game you received free in Plus, and it requires said free game to play it, you will not be able to access these Add-Ons if you choose not to renew your membership. However, if you decide to re-activate your membership, you will once again be able to play all games downloaded from the Instant Game Collection along with all purchased DLC for these games. Alternatively, you may also purchase the specific game to access any purchased Add-Ons for the game as well.

Games purchased using the discount are yours for keeps, even if you stop subscribing:

> Q: So while I can only access games downloaded free as long as I’m a Plus member, what about games and other content I purchase with a Plus discount?
>
> A: Any content you purchase with a Plus discount is yours to keep, regardless of you membership status.

Comment: and games I purchased using playstation plus discount?

Comment: Yours for keeps, even if you stop subscribing :)

Comment: Yup, the best way to remember what @rense said is that if you put any actual money toward actually purchasing a game, they can't take it back from you.

Comment: yep, they all did stay when I renewed :)

Answer (score 4):

They stay connected to your account but you cannot access them when your subscription ends.

When you renew your subscription you get back what you had before plus the new items that are available at that time (I believe you need to start the download or add to library before they get connected to your account)

If your subscription ends and you don't resubscribe until several months later, you will not get the content you missed out in between.

Comment: yes but for example if i renew in January and I already got Decembers games, I'm good?

Comment: Yes, everything you already have you will get back :)  
Normally the games also stay in the catalog more than a month.  
But if lets say a game gets added in February and is removed from the catalog of free games in May and you only renew subscription in June, you will not have that game but you will have all the games in the catalog in June and everything you had before.

Comment: @miva2 What about progress? Say I finish a (free for PS+) game 50% and my subscription ends. Three months later, I renew it. Is my progress still there or would I have to start from the beginning?

Comment: @Snowman Your locally saved progress will stay yours. You will not be able to play the game unless you buy it separately or subscribe to ps+ again. I am unsure what happens to cloud saves. You can back up local savefiles if you want.